# How to Center Scroll Bar in HorizontalScrollView Android

Tags: android

The question is pretty much self explanatory but I was wondering how to see the center part of the HorizontalScrollView when it first appears on the screen. It would display exactly as if you had scrolled to the center of the view.

So far I have tried:

```
scrollView.scrollTo(x, y);
```

Where 'y' has been 0 and 'x' has been half the width of the contents of scrollView.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks,

Evan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use:

```
scrollView.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        scrollView.scrollTo(x, y);
    }
});
```

Comment: Ah, definitely this was the real problem. I'll just remove my answer to avoid confusion